# Is SQL Azure accessible from Windows Store and WP8 apps?

Tags: azure-sql-database, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8

I need a DB in the cloud that my pair of apps will write to (WP8 apps) and read from (Windows Store app). Is this possible? Has anybody done it that has advice on best practices/how-tos/gotchas, and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at [Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/), that most likely matches what you're after in a much better way...

Comment: I looked into that earlier, but I'm not sure that the Windows 8 app could access records written to the DB by the WP8 app...

Comment: I'm czeching out the whol Azure world in more detail.

Comment: What "scares" me is the name: Windows Azure MOBILE Services; perhaps it's a misnomer, but it makes me think it won't work on desktops/laptops, IOW that your device needs to be a mobile one - phones or tablets only.

Comment: The app that will insert and update will be on WP8; the app that will read from the DB will be a Windows Store app.

Comment: I still don't see what you're worried about if both apps will be reading from the same database.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's the MOBILE that I'm "worried" about; can an app running on a desktop or laptop really expect to be able to participate in a mobile experience/technology? I reckon SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure Database or some such) is probably the path I should take. But I still don't know how to go about that (I need a tutorial).